# Search drop-down barely visible -- what style needs to change?

Tags: 2013, css, search-box

I had to move the search box into the DeltaSuiteLinks area in the topnav.  The problem is now that when you begin typing a search query -- and SharePoint begins to anticipate the query in a drop-down, it is nearly a white on white result.  I have not been able to figure out what style in being used in this area.

[image]

My question is what style do I need to change so that the text will show up on this drop-down white area